# <li> tag appearing around a kohana form input

Tags: html, tags, kohana

I am developing a form in kohana 3.2 and I have noticed that when the form input renders I am getting a html list tag around the form input. For testing I have removed all CSS for clarity. The piece of code in question is as follows.

```
echo $form->open('user/login');
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>'.$form->input('username').'</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $form->input('password');
echo '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo $form->submit(NULL, __('Login'));
echo '</td></tr></table>';
echo $form->close();
```

When this renders I am seeing the list tags around the inputs. In Firebug I see the following

```
<form accept-charset="utf-8" method="post" action="/newsite/index.php/user/login">
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<li>
<input type="text" class="text" name="username">
</li>
</td>
<td>
<li>
<input type="text" class="text" name="password">
</li>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" class="submit" value="Login">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

I have had a read of the kohana API documentation and have checked a number of examples similar to my own code and I can find no reason for these unwanted list tags.

Can anyone explain where they are coming from and how to stop them appearing?

Kind Regards

Richard

Comment: Have you overridden the input helper by chance to be wrapped in li's?

Comment: This is a clean installation of kohana 3.2 and there are no helpers for anything at the moment

Answer (score 0):

No way.

Due to [Kohana 3.2 Form helper Docs](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/Form#input) it only returns `'<input'.HTML::attributes($attributes).' />'`.

Probably you have HTML tag mistype (not-closed tag, excess tag etc.) and browser tries to fix it adding new tags...

Answer (score 0):

please try the following code

```
echo form::open('user/login');
echo '<table>';
echo '<tr><td>'.form::input('username').'</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo form::input('password');
echo '</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td>&nbsp;</td>';
echo '<td>';
echo form::submit(NULL, __('Login'));
echo '</td></tr></table>';
echo form::close();
```